# How do I open my Twitter DM to all my followers?

Tags: twitter

I want to allow all the followers (I don't follow most of them) able to send me a DM.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings =>  [Privacy and Safety => Direct Messages](https://twitter.com/settings/direct_messages) tab in enable DM's for everyone.

[image]